# error: c:/wamp64 or PHP in PATH

Tags: php

I recently was working with composer and php and now when I try to access any one of my other files through localhost/foldername/file1.php etc, I receive the above error in the CMD. I uninstalled composer and deleted the environmental variable and restarted WAMP but I still cannot access folders in localhost. When I type in localhost it takes me to one particular folder found at C:\wamp64\www\Laravel.
I know it has something to do with having PHP in my PATH but what does this mean? Please help me!

Comment: Please post your `PATH` variable in your question.

Comment: How do I access that?

Comment: This is the error I get in the CMD:

Comment: Sorry,

There is an error.

It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment variable PATH
C:\php_youtube

There is Wampserver path (c:/wamp64)
into Windows PATH environnement variable: (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.35)

Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
is detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.


Press ENTER to continue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I meet the same problem on Wamp version 3.1.4_x64 with PHP version 7.2.10 and now it working for me!

It not need a path on a PHP version in the Windows PATH environment variable.
So you must remove this path from your environment variable.
And next step just Exit Wamp and open again!

I hope that my answer i'll help you. Good luck guys :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you installed Laravel in your home directory. Look inside of your home directory with your file explorer, if you see an index.php or index.html rename this to anything other that index. For example change index.php to not_index.php and then try to visit you local host in a browser.

Side note, XAMPP is much more user friendly than WAMPP could ever hope to be.

Answer (score 0):

Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
may be detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.